# Conditional expectaction with probabilities for a sum of independent random variable

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, conditional-expectation, discrete-distributions

I have a r.v $S_N$ built as a sum of Bernoulli with parameter $p$. So $S_N = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_N$. There is a second variable N, such that $N \sim Poisson(\lambda) $.

I have to compute:

1. $P(S_N=0)$
2. $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(S_N \ | \ N = 4 )$
3. $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(S_N \ | \ N )$

Now, for the first point, I need to think my sum of Bernoulli as a Binomial. Thus:

$$
P(S_N = 0) = \binom{n}{0} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = (1-p)^n
$$

However, i'm stuck with the two expectations. But i remember that for the conditional expectaction for two discrete random variables it holds:

$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X \ | \ Y = k ) = \sum_x x \ f_{X|Y}(x|y)
$$

Comment: I am confused. Are $Y$ and $N$ the same?

Comment: What is the role of the second variable $Y$ should it be $N$?

Comment: Sorry, my fault.

Comment: Since $N$ is random, $S_N$ cannot be a Binomial $\mathcal B(N,p)$.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the problem, since I supposed that the N in $X_N$ was only an index

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=poisson+binomial+expectation.

Comment: $S_N$ will be Poisson with rate $\lambda p$. With this you can answer question 1 (but probably you are supposed to compute it manually).

Comment: There are already good answers but I'll add that the $S_N$ is a [Compound Poisson Random Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution).

Comment: @abstrusiosity $S_n$ is constructed by compounding, but effectively this 'compound Poisson random' variable equals a 'Poisson random variable' which is a simpler way to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Problem 2, $N=4$ is a constant. Thus, $S_N$ is a binomial variable with the mean equals $4p$  (assuming the Bernoulli takes value either 1 or 0).

For Problem 3: In general for the binomial distribution with $N=n$, the mean is $np$. Now for $N$ is a random variable, the mean then is $E[np]=\bar{n}p$. In particular when $N$ is of Poisson distribution, $\bar{n}=\lambda$, thus the mean is $\lambda p$.